# How can i tell if my computer is connected to the 2.4ghz or 5ghz wifi ?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

How can i tell if my computer is connected to the 2.4ghz or 5ghz wifi ?

Our access point outputs both, but im trying to trouble shoot it and wondered if there was a place i could see on my mac what its currently connected to ?

Im running OSX 10.10.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is.  Hold the option key and click on your wifi icon on the top right toolbar on your macbook.  You'll see which band (2.4GHz or 5GHz) you are connected to as well as your RSSI (signal strength) and your WiFi Rate and much much more.